# CUDA only finds 9gb free of 11gb total on gtx 1080 ti

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

when I open a tf session, I find that tensorflow can only get 9gb of the 11gb.  This is on both Linux and Windows systems (different machines) so it's not specific to my setup.  Was talking to others as well that had the same issue.  Doesn't anyone know how to resolve this?

name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.683
pciBusID: 0000:04:00.0
totalMemory: 11.00GiB freeMemory: 9.10GiB

### Update

this is NOT a Tensorflow issue -- i've been able to replicate the problem directly from CUDA code using 'cudaMemGetInfo" function.

GPU Device 0: "GeForce GTX 1080 Ti" with compute capability 6.1

free: 9770575052, tot: 11811160064

Comment: This would not surprise me if this is a Windows 10 system. With the WDDM 2.0 driver, GPU memory allocation is in the hands of the OS, and multiple observations show that it makes only about 81% of the total GPU memory available to CUDA applications (vs. around 95% with the WDDM 1.x driver of Windows 7). I have no explanation for your observation regarding Linux; it would be best to do cross-OS comparisons on the physically identical system, e.g. a dual boot configuration. This questions seems to be off-topic, as it pertains to the configuration of "general computing hardware/software".

Comment: "...off-topic..." -- depends on the solution.  Is there some simple CUDA/c++ code out there that you know of which I could grab and run in visual studio to test your hypothesis?  At least i see there is a CUDA function for this....[link](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15668-s11/www/cuda-doc/html/group__CUDART__MEMORY_gd5d6772f4b2f3355078ecd6059e6aa74.html)

Comment: And it is NOT windows specific.  The same issue shows up on Ubuntu on a different machine.  I disagree with your assessmen to do it on the same machine....the conclusion is stronger that it is NOT a general computing issue if it's happening on different systems.  Perhaps this is a github thing...not SO

Comment: agreed, my Gigabyte Windforce RTX 2080 Ti with 11GB OC also has this issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58866389/why-does-my-nvidia-rtx-2080ti-with-11gb-gpu-only-has-9gb-memory

Comment: @Franva I found it's better to buy the Titan cards since you can use the TCC driver instead of WDDM on windows.

Comment: @user3496060 no money for the Titan cards >_<; you can try this cmd to see its memory: nvidia-smi